# Get primary key of a MySQL insert using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I have looked through the documentation for this, but it is all about auto-increment.

I generate a key using a trigger and MySQL's `UUID()` function (I need these keys to be unique across databases that may or may not ever interact).

I use a trigger to generate the `UUID()`

How would I retrieve that key on an insert?

Comment: Which PHP MySQL functions are you using? PDO, mysqli, deprecated mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the UUID created by the trigger on a variable (@last_uuid)

```
CREATE TRIGGER ai_uuidtable
AFTER INSERT ON uuidtable
FOR EACH ROW
SET @last_uuid = NEW.uuid;
```

Then you can retrieve the value using a query

```
SELECT @last_uuid
```

Comment: As per the edit I just made, I use a trigger on the insert to generate the UUID.

Comment: Updated my answer for trigger generated uuid

Comment: I like this answer because PHP has nothing to do with the created UUID

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't working... I am probably doing something wrong. The `SELECT @last_uuid` is returning 1. My actual trigger is a bit different, as I do the trigger before the insert, where I `SET NEW.uuid = UUID(); SET @last_uuid = NEW.uuid;` The row correctly has a uuid, but as I said, my `SELECT @last_uuid` returns 1...

Comment: The connection was being reset, which killed all the variables. I had to use mysqli's `multi_query`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make TWO queries :

```
SELECT UUID();
```

save it in a variable ( `$uuid` ) and then run the `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, text) VALUES ($uuid, 'text');
```

Comment: according to your comment, I've changed my response! hope that it's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could move the UUID generation to the PHP side instead of using MySQL. Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049455/how-to-create-a-uuid-in-php-without-a-external-library